# Caching of static assets in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I came across an issue with a Symfony2 page. There appears to be some sort of not-client-side caching of static assets, eg. a zip file going on. For a few hours after updating the page the old file is downloaded and then it suddenly updates. I strongly suspect this may have something to do with the server or some proxy configuration so I doubt this has anything to do with Symfony itself as it would make little sense, but just as a sanity check - does S2 cache such files as well?

Comment: @voters That is a correct question. It is not too broad, it is not unclear, it has no code exemple because none are needed. We should leave it open.

Comment: Thanks, I won't defend my own question, esp. since it already solved my problem, but I think the answer is actually a very useful one as a future reference.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is too broad? I ask whether Symfony2 caches static assets or no. This is a question about a particular behavior of a particular version of particular framework concerning a particular kind of assets. What should be narrowed down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony2 uses a cache for assets and the pages.

For pages, clearing the cache is easy, this console command is sufficient

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=ENVIRONMENT YOUR WORKING IN
```

For the assets, there are multiple ways:

The assets got installed via symlink, those could be broken. To restore them:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

The assets got installed with a hardcopy, so you need to overwrite them after a change:

```
php app/console assets:install
```

The assets got dumped. If they got dumped, only a dump will update those assets:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

The dump will usually only be used in productive environments.

Comment: Good to know! I have only FTP access though. I know how to dump cache (delete dirs). Is there a way to call these commands without command line access?

Comment: Not that I could recall. Those commands can only be executed from the command line. But you could write yourself an php file that executes those command line commands for you.

Comment: @konrad glad that I could help